# Money-Rails Gem: Humanized_money in Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, money-rails

In my Donations Model, I have monetized the amount_cents column

I need the humanized version of the donation amount (Eg. 643.50) in the Model so I can generate and send a PDF receipt to the donor.

I've tried humanized_money(self.amount) and self.amount.humanized_money but get the error :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `humanized_money' for #<Donation:0x007fa687ebb678>
```

How can I get this humanized form in the Models?

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :donatable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :added_by_user, foreign_key: "added_by", class_name: "User"

  store_accessor :details, :method

  monetize :amount_cents

  def donations_this_week(branch_id)
    sum =  Donation.sum(:amount_cents).to_money
    return humanized_money(sum)
  end

  def receipt
    Receipts::Receipt.new(
        id: id,
        product: "GoRails",
        message: "This receipt is to acknowledge that we have received a donation with the below details from #{self.donatable.name}",
        company: {
            name: self.donatable.branch.organization.name,
            address: "#{self.donatable.branch.address_line_1}\n#{self.donatable.branch.address_line_2}\n#{self.donatable.branch.email}\n#{self.donatable.branch.legal_details}",
            email: self.donatable.branch.email,
            logo: self.donatable.branch.organization.logo.url(:medium),
        },
        line_items: [
            ["Date",           created_at.to_s],
            ["Donor Name", self.donatable.name],
            ["Amount",         humanized_money(self.amount)],
            ["Payment Method",     self.method],
        ]
    )
  end
end
```

Below is the database schema :

```
create_table "donations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "donatable_type"
t.integer  "donatable_id"
t.integer  "amount_cents"
t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
t.datetime "date"
t.integer  "added_by"
t.jsonb    "details",        default: {}, null: false
```

Comment: You should post your Donation model, particularly the the part where you monetize the amount field. Right off, I can tell you the problem is that you're calling `humanized_money` on a `Donation` object. You need to call that method with a `Money` object as the parameter.

Comment: post the code where you are calling `humanize_money`. I am guessing that maybe you are calling `humanized_money` on something that is not a money_object

Comment: Attached the model! Thanks!

Comment: could you check the column type of `amount ` in your database?

Comment: Attached the database schema!

Comment: the helper calls a money method that can be called directly in the model without include the whole helper in the model https://stackoverflow.com/a/49285750/1536309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do NOT need to include the helper in your model.

```
price_options = {
  :no_cents_if_whole => MoneyRails::Configuration.no_cents_if_whole.nil? ? true : MoneyRails::Configuration.no_cents_if_whole,
  :symbol => true
}
your_money_column.format(price_options)
```

[source code on github](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/master/lib/money-rails/helpers/action_view_extension.rb#L8-L27)

Answer (score 5):

To do this without loading everything in `ActionView::Base`. You can just do

```
return ActionController::Base.helpers.humanized_money sum
```

Answer (score 4):

Including ActionView::Base will add a LOT of extra stuff to your model, do NOT do it this way.

Do this instead:

```
include MoneyRails::ActionViewExtension
```

This way you get all (5 at the time of this post) of the money view helper methods.

Comment: THIS! Even saw solutions that this `ActionView::Base.new.humanized_money(10)` Especially when you have a plain api and dont even use action view...

Answer (score 2):

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `humanized_money' for #<Donation:0x007fa687ebb678>
```

From the error message its clear that you are calling the `humanized_money` helper method for a `Donation` object, NOT a `Money` object. That's why its failing.

If you monetized the `amount_cents` column properly already, then automagically, your `amount` column will be of `Money` type i.e. `Money` object which you can pass to the `humanized_money` helper method as parameter like this:

```
humanized_money amount
```

I would say, check the type of your `amount` and make sure its a `Money` object which it should be if you properly monetized `amount_cents` column of your `Donation` model. That's why it's not working in this case.

#### Update

Looks like `humanized_money` is defined in the `action_view_extension` of the [money-rails gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/30f07b91a9c17d512f537583c02b4a62485ad0f3/lib/money-rails/helpers/action_view_extension.rb) and expected to work in views only. Not in model.

A possible solution to this problem would be to include [ActionView::Base](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/ea559cf7d8dc341827f92d4f41a7211b9df99ba7/lib/money-rails/hooks.rb#L22-L27) module in the Model, that would make the `humanized_money` method available inside the model. And then you can call humanized_money in your model like:

```
 include ActionView::Base
 humanized_money(sum)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, when I run Donation.last.amount on the console, I get : => #<Money fractional:3400 currency:USD>

Comment: on which line its failing? `return humanized_money(sum)` OR `["Amount",         humanized_money(self.amount)]`?

Comment: Okay, can you inspect this: `puts Donation.sum(:amount_cents).to_money.inspect` what do you see?

Comment: `(0.4ms)  SELECT SUM("donations"."amount_cents") FROM "donations"
#<Money fractional:33985700 currency:USD>
=> nil`

Comment: ok, so its a `Money` object. Then I don't see any reason for its failing :(
Seems to be, it does not work in a Model class for some reason. Can you try it in your view? I am sure it will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87337/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-michael-victor).

Answer (score 0):

KM Rakibul is right about the helper not being included in ActiveRecord but they are hooked to [ActionView::Base](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/ea559cf7d8dc341827f92d4f41a7211b9df99ba7/lib/money-rails/hooks.rb) so to include them use:

```
include ActionView::Base
```